# A for loop in C using an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've created an array named a that can hold 100 double values,

```
double a[100];
```

I set the first element of the array a to NUM, which is a symbolic constant defined early in my code.

```
a[0] = NUM
```

I'm curious as to how I would write a for loop that sets each remaining value of a to the value of the preceding element plus 0.1. For example, the second element in the array is the first plus 0.1. I've tried doing

```
for(i=1; i<=99; i=+0.1)
```

But I think something is wrong with my initialization of `i`

Comment: You need to learn how for loops work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `i` to index the array, not to store the value you should put on the array. Remember you can use expressions to access the array, like `a[i - 1]`

```
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + 0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;    
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       a[i] = NUM + 0.1 * i;
```

dont forget to tell the type int !

Comment: You are not allowed to declare the int in the loop.  It must be declared before.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if (i == 0)
        a[i] = NUM;
    else
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + .1;
}
```

Your array definition includes the step.  So your array would run about 1000 times, at 1, 1.1, 1.2, but a[1.1] isn't a valid index of your array.  Use i to index the array, and then retrieve the previous value to set the next.

Comment: `a[0] = NUM; for (i = 1...)` and save yourself the repeated/pointless if() test.

Comment: That would be more efficient, but I chose to be more explicit/verbose for the example.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can understand that this is one of your first program in C/C++, so I think that you need to start from basic things and learn how to do it properly, before doing it elegantly.

http://ideone.com/RGZgXL

```
 for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
     if(i == 0) { // if we are on the first element, set it to NUM
         array[i] = NUM;
     } else { // otherwise make the sum
         array[i] = array[i-1] + STEP;
     }
 }
```

In the link you'll find the code and some comments that I hope will help you in understanding it.

Cheers

Comment: They should set `array[0]` first and then loop starting from `i = 1`; otherwise you end up with a pointless branch in your loop.

Comment: Yes I know it. But in this way the code i more clear because respect how he has described the problem. After that he will be able to fix it :)